# Animate UITextView between ViewControllers like Instagram does

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitextview, transition

I've been wondering for quite some time how Instagram implemented their text editor transition:

[image]

On a first guess, I'd say they are performing both the text editing and the "movement" on the same UIViewController, but at the level of complexity they have, they must have found a way to make the transition from VC A to VC B, where VC B does the entire text editing.I'm starting to think that the VC A (movement VC) is holding a "snapshot" of the UITextView, where VC B actually hold the object (then the user can edit it).

I'm **not** looking for a drag & drop code solution. I'm trying to think out loud about what is the possibilities to implement the same behavior they have, in terms of correct architecture and user experience.

**Thank you for your time,**

**Roi**

Comment: I really think it’s just a view that overlays the current VC. As for the animation, it shouldn’t be so difficult. Maybe storing the current CGRect of the label and animating the movement to the center and the font size change.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla If so, where is the entire text edit logic is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is best solved using a custom class derived from `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. I've done it before with logos transitioning from one view controller to the next. The official docs are here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning and there are numerous examples of how to create a class on the internet.

Comment: Hey Daniel. I used this class multiple times but for stuff which is not related to UITextView, usually for images and videos which is easier to communicate. I'm wondering how they passed the UITextView from one VC to another while making the transition smooth. Super hard.